# Construir Data Frame com Função "get"

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, r, data.frame

Esse é meu data.frame:

```
data<-read.csv2("NewEXEMPL.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")

head(data,5)
    DATE   P.A      i.A     S.A       w.A   b.A   P.B      i.B    S.B         w.B   b.B      P.C     i.C       S.C   w.C   b.C
1 jun/79 16.86 59.67768 12.3125 0.4291845 497.9 10.38 28.41693 23.000 0.000862813 16.86 59.67768 12.3125 0.4291845 497.9 10.38
2 jul/79 16.69 59.90459 12.2500 0.4177109 533.6 10.48 28.73513 24.250 0.000838926 16.69 59.90459 12.2500 0.4177109 533.6 10.48
3 ago/79 16.62 60.28277 12.0625 0.4046945 542.7 10.55 28.90646 29.500 0.000814996 16.62 60.28277 12.0625 0.4046945 542.7 10.55
4 set/79 16.90 60.43405 12.3125 0.4085802 533.3 10.54 29.17570 36.125 0.000821018 16.90 60.43405 12.3125 0.4085802 533.3 10.54
5 out/79 17.05 60.73660 12.0000 0.4301075 495.3 10.59 29.59179 39.125 0.000849257 17.05 60.73660 12.0000 0.4301075 495.3 10.59
       P.D     i.D          S.D      w.D        b.D
1 28.41693  12.400 42.404741100 12.00000  0.2405581
2 28.73513  12.980 42.781114500 12.37500  0.2379819
3 28.90646  13.220 43.241126500 11.06250  0.2279202
4 29.17570 495.300  8.700000000 26.27222 18.2500000
5 29.59179  39.125  0.000849257 10.76000 54.1561672
```

tem cerca de 400 linhas.

Nesse código abaixo eu gostaria de ter para cada país (A, B e C) um data.frame ("NEW") com as colunas: `P.A`, `P.D`, `i.A`, `i.D` e  `S.A`. Ou seja, a minha referencia será sempre o país D. Gostaria de fazer isso com a funcao "get" mas nao estou conseguindo. Alguma ajuda?

```
mylist<-c("A","B","C") # São os países
for (cno in 1:3){
  country<-mylist[cno]
NEW<-data.frame(get(paste("S,i",country,sep=".",data)))
  }
```

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `get()` não é adequada para o que você quer fazer. Ela pega apenas um objeto por vez.

Para pegar mais de um objeto você teria que utilizar a função `mget`, mas mesmo assim não faz muito sentido nesse caso, já que você pode selecionar colunas pelo nome em um `data.frame`.

Uma forma de resolver seu problema seria a seguinte:

```
mylist<-c("A","B","C") 

colunas <- lapply(mylist, function(x) paste(c("P", "i", "S"), x, sep = "."))

lista_de_dfs <- list()

for(i in seq_along(colunas))
  lista_de_dfs[[mylist[[i]]]] <- data[c(colunas[[i]], "P.D", "i.D")]
```

E o objeto `lista_de_dfs` é uma lista com os `data.frames` que você quer, por exemplo:

```
lista_de_dfs[["A"]]
    P.A      i.A     S.A      P.D     i.D
1 16.86 59.67768 12.3125 28.41693  12.400
2 16.69 59.90459 12.2500 28.73513  12.980
3 16.62 60.28277 12.0625 28.90646  13.220
4 16.90 60.43405 12.3125 29.17570 495.300
5 17.05 60.73660 12.0000 29.59179  39.125
```

Se você quiser jogar esses `data.frames` para o ambiente global (o que eu não recomendaria, é muito mais fácil trabalhar com eles na lista), basta rodar `list2env(lista_de_dfs, globalenv())`.

Apenas para ilustrar, se você quiser fazer usando o `mget()` -- o que ***não recomendo***, pois além de muito mais complicado é muito mais lento --, a lógica seria bastante similar:

```
mylist<-c("A","B","C") 

colunas <- lapply(mylist, function(x) paste(c("P", "i", "S"), x, sep = "."))

lista_de_dfs <- list()

for(i in seq_along(colunas))
  lista_de_dfs[[mylist[[i]]]] <- data.frame(mget(c(colunas[[i]], "P.D", "i.D"), as.environment(data)))
```

Não há nenhuma razão para fazer dessa forma ao invés de trabalhar com a forma natural de seleção de `data.frames`.

Comment: Valeu, Carlos! Ajudou bastante.