# Com loop utilizar colunas em objetos no R

Tags: r, funções, loop, objetos

Olá, criei mais de 8 mil objetos (Dataframes) no R. Entretanto ao tentar utilizar, em loop, uma das colunas de cada objeto, sempre tenho como respostas que a função utilizada não lê objetos não númericos. 
como soluciono isso?

```
for(i in 10:13) { 
    nam <- paste("mu04mun_", i, sep = "")
    d <- paste0("sub04mun", i, "$des_flo_04")
    assign(nam, qnorm(d))
}
```

> Error in qnorm(d) : Argumento não-numérico para função matemática

Comment: Experimente `qnorm(get(d))`.

Answer (score 1):

Você está aplicando a função `qnorm()` em um vetor de texto. Veja:

```
d <- "texto"
qnorm(d)
#> Error in qnorm(d): Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Aparentemente sua intenção era rodar `qnorm()` na coluna `des_flo_04` do data frame `sub04mun`. Para isso, você precisa chamar o objeto, não o texto.

A sugestão do Rui não vai funcionar diretamente, pois você não pode colocar o `$` dentro do `get`, mas você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
for(i in 10:13) { 
    nam <- paste("mu04mun_", i, sep = "")
    d <- paste0("sub04mun", i)
    assign(nam, qnorm(d)[["des_flo_04"]])
}
```

É  importante notar que esse tipo de código não é recomendado. O ideal aqui é você trabalhar com listas (salvar os data frames em uma lista) e operar em cima das listas: [para exemplo, veja essa resposta aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127449/construir-data-frame-com-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-get/127530#127530)